# Gitpod cannot resolve workspace image: hostname required on workspace start

Tags: amazon-eks, workspace, self-hosting, gitpod

I've gitpod selfhosted in EKS. When I try to start a new workspace I have this error:

> Request createWorkspace failed with message: 13 INTERNAL: cannot
> resolve workspace image: hostname required

Unknown Error: { "code": -32603 }

I haven't found any solution.
Any idea?
Thank you

Here my gitpod-config.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
authProviders: []
blockNewUsers:
  enabled: false
  passlist: []
certificate:
  kind: secret
  name: https-certificates
containerRegistry:
  inCluster: true
  s3storage:
    bucket: custom-bucket
    certificate:
      kind: secret
      name: object-storage-gitpod-token
database:
  inCluster: false
  external:
    certificate:
      kind: secret
      name: mysql-gitpod-token
domain: my-domain.com
imagePullSecrets: null
jaegerOperator:
  inCluster: true
kind: Full
metadata:
  region: eu-west-1
objectStorage:
  inCluster: true
observability:
  logLevel: info
repository: eu.gcr.io/gitpod-core-dev/build
workspace:
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: "1"
      memory: 2Gi
  runtime:
    containerdRuntimeDir: /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io
    containerdSocket: /run/containerd/containerd.sock
    fsShiftMethod: shiftfs
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run v2022.03.1 and now I have all three DNS records configured.
It works.

Thanks everybody who response

Answer (score 0):

I'm a Gitpodder and wrote most of the Installer. This is usually down to a misconfiguration.

Can you post your `config.yaml` (redacting the `domain`) please and hopefully I'll be able to see the issue?

Comment: Thank you. I've poste my code in main post. Do you also need eks-cluster.yaml?

Comment: I have two more problems: 
1- where can I verify the installation? On my mac the command      kubectl get pods
return command not found: kubctl       and also on ec2 workspace and service.

2- the command    make auth     return error (Error from server (NotFound): configmaps "auth-providers-config" not found)

Comment: The only thing that jumps out is that you've configured the `containerRegistry` to use an S3 bucket, but have got `inCluster = true`. However, I wouldn't normally expect that to cause a problem - for the purposes of clarity, can you either set one or other?

Comment: With other issue, looks like you need to install `kubectl` - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/

Comment: The `make auth` isn't used in the guide any more. I thought that had been removed actually

Comment: I just reinstalled all, but now I've got 504 response (it happens many times and I need to destroy all and reinstall).
When I run kubectl get pods I've got  Unable to connect to the server: EOF

In my gitpod-config.yaml the value of containerRegistry incCluster is changed due install from false to true

Comment: I've just installe newer version 2022.01.1 and I've got 504 (like the previous versione. Same problem :-/ )

Answer (score 0):

Check your `.env` file has an entry for the `CERTIFICATE_ARN=` and that the cert has 3 entries for the base domain.

e.g. if DOMAIN=mygitpod.domain.com

The cert needs these three:

```
mygitpod.domain.com
*.mygitpod.domain.com
*.ws.mygitpod.domain.com`
```

Answer (score 0):

i had this error and i resolved it by adding a DNS record for

```
$DOMAIN
*.$DOMAIN
*.ws.$DOMAIN`
```